# Why can't NPM read my dependencies?

Tags: android, node.js, npm, ionic-framework

I'm trying to start a new ionic project. I got this far and I'm very proud of that. Though I'm halted at ionic setup sass. I was able to 'ionic platform android'

I think the problem lies in the open 'C:\Users\ALIR\package.json'

It should be looking in : 'C:\Users\ALIR\Documents\Ionic\tutorials\test'

Also this line is concerning: '"C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nod
    ejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"'
All of these slashes sem inappropiate.

```
C:\Users\ALIR\Documents\Ionic\tutorials\test>ionic setup sass
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\ALIR\package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directo
ry.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\ALIR\Documents\Ionic\tutorials\test
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ALIR\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno 34
npm
Error running npm install

C:\Users\ALIR\Documents\Ionic\tut
```

orials\test>

Comment: Try running `npm install` from that directory first.

Comment: ok, I'll try that. @JeremyWilken         
`C:\Users\ALIR\Documents\Ionic\tutorials\test>npm install  npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\ALIR\package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directo
ry.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601`

Comment: I'm not sure where it's supposed to point, but it likely should not be pointing here `path C:\Users\ALIR\package.json`. I would expect it to be something like `C:\Users\ALIR\Documents\Ionic\tutorials\test>`

Answer (score 1):

So I had to create a package.json at `Users\Alir`. I just took the one from the todo folder. I'm sure this is not good, but what else can I do.

Now everything is progressing.

Comment: I took my package.json file located at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm ... seems to have done the trick. Even though I also have no idea why I'm doing this.